# v8: why is function call inside javascript faster as a function call from c++

Tags: javascript, c++, performance, v8

I have following script:

```
var rnd = 0;
function test(){
    rnd += dummy();
}
for(i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    test();
log(rnd);
rnd = 0;
```

log prints something on the terminal.
dummy is a c++ callback function that returns random numbers:

```
void dummy(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &args)
{
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(rand() % 10);
}
```

The time to compile and run it in v8 is 828 milliseconds

after this, i get the function handle in c++ from test and call it in a loop the same amount. This takes 2195 milliseconds.

Why is it so slow and is it possible to get it faster?

C++ Snipped:

```
 auto global = context->Global();
 auto function = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(global->Get(v8::String::New("test")));
 auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 for(size_t i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
      function->Call(global, 0, 0);
 }
 auto milli = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
 cout << "time: " << milli.count() << endl;
```

Comment: V8 likes to "cheat" JS when it knows there's no way to prove it did so. try memorizing the values and watch the JS perf get worse.

Comment: do you mean that i should save the values somewhere or do calcualtions to get a result? I changed my script now to add the values to rnd instead of assigning it and print the value at the end. Now it is 828 to 2195 milliseconds

Comment: V8 can inline the call to `dummy`. C++ compiler can't. I'm pretty sure that's what is happening.

Comment: @scyomantion: well that's closer, the gap narrowed... Whatever the gritty explanation, it's an encouraging example of runtime optimization that was un-imaginable just a few years ago.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: is there a possibility to prevent it from inlining?

Comment: Also, you're not measuring the C++ perfs but the performances of the C++ side of V8 (which is not exactly the same thing). I think that for the C++ side no optimizations occurs for the loop, but in runtime V8 can optimize the loop, and so optimize the number of calls.

Comment: @scyomantion: I don't know. My point is pretty much the same as Synxis, you are comparing a "manually built piece of unoptimised V8 functionality, to compiled code code that has been optimised by V8". It's a bit like compiling with gcc using -O0 and compare that with -O2, ad wonder why the latter is faster...

Comment: if i want to process mouch data in javascript, is it faster to implement the processing loop in javascript and provide a callback function to get the next data portion? My first intention was to call the js function for each data portion. Maybe I have to do both things and run a benchmark

Answer (score 1):

Answer is quite simple - switching between JS/C++ code is slow.

When you call C++ code from JavaScript V8 have to do trip JS code (`test` function)-> C++ code (`dummy function`) -> JS code (back to `test` function)

When you call JavaScript that call C++ code from C++ code, V8 have to do following trip: C++ code -> JS code (`test` function) -> C++ code (`dummy function`) -> JS code (back to `test` function) -> C++ code.